# JavaScript String Generator - Not Working (Sublime Text 3)

Tags: javascript, string, sublimetext3, build-system

I am using Sublime Text 3 and whenever I build it with my build system for JavaScript. It gives me an error. Code below as well as error:

```
function makeid(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(makeid(5));
```

And then the error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc', 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Projects\\Password Generator\\script.js']]
[dir: C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\Password Generator]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\National Instruments\Shared\OpenVINO\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps]
[Finished]
```

I tried running the code and it didn't work and I'm expecting it to generate me a random string.

Answer (score 0):

Your "build system for JavaScript" expects you to have a `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc` binary - that's an obviously macOS path, and you're evidently running on Windows.

You'll want e.g. [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) if you want to run console JavaScript on Windows, and then fix your build system to use node instead.

Comment: How do I fix my build system or edit it?

Comment: I don't know how you've set it up in the first place to use `jsc`.

Comment: @Theodore there is plenty of information here and on the web in general on how to create and edit Sublime build systems.

Answer (score -2):

To generate a JavaScript string in Sublime Text editor, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Sublime Text editor and create a new file by selecting "File" > "New File" from the menu or by pressing "Ctrl+N" on Windows or "Cmd+N" on Mac.
2. Type the following code to create a string variable and assign a value to it:
   var myString = "Hello, world!";
3. Save the file by selecting "File" > "Save" from the menu or by pressing "Ctrl+S" on Windows or "Cmd+S" on Mac.
4. Choose a location and name for the file and save it with a .js extension, for example "myFile.js".
5. To test the code, you can open a new browser window and create a script tag to reference the file,
6. Finally, open the HTML file in a web browser and check the console output to see the string value printed:

Comment: This doesn't even come close to answering the question.